# not able to modify outer function data through inner function

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong here. I want to get same output with both console.log() statements.

```
createModel(){
  getvalue("asdfgh");
}
var myservice;
function getvalue(value){
  myservice = value; console.log("inside: "+JSON.stringify(myservice));
  //prints: asdfg
}
createModel();
console.log("outside: "+JSON.stringify(myservice));//prints: undefined
return (myservice);
```

Comment: Your code as posted works fine. I suspect that your *actual* code does some asynchronous operation in `getvalue()`.

Comment: [See this question for more information.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I specified 'async: false' & it worked fine.

Comment: Well that's good, but note that `async: false` will generally result in poor user experience; the user's browser freezes up while waiting for the response. Chrome may even pop up a warning message.

Comment: so how should it be handled?

Comment: Do things *asynchronously* and process results in a callback function. That's the general pattern for coding in JavaScript.

Comment: thanks man, I'll make appropriate changes in my code.